# can i add dots to pure css slider?

Tags: html, css, slider

Can I add dots to my pure css slider? I am a newbie in css so I still don't know how to add that.  I tried to make it but the dot does not sync with my image. I only use css at my slider. Can you help me to make dots with my script?

```css
.banner {
 width: 100%;
 position: relative;
 z-index:0;
 height:120  !important;
 background: no-repeat center center scroll
}
@keyframes slider {
    0%  { left: 0; }
    30% { left: 0; }
    40% { left: -100%;}
    70% { left: -100%;}
    80% { left: -200%;}
    95% { left: -200%;}
}
#slider {
 overflow: hidden;
}
#slider figure img {
 width: 20%;
 float: left;
}
#slider figure {
 position: relative;
 width: 500%;
 margin: 0;
 left: 0;
 text-align: left;
 font-size: 0;
 animation: 20s slider infinite; 
}
```

```html
 <div class="banner-container revolution">
     <div class="banner" id="slider">
         <figure>
             <ul>
                 <li> <img src="slide1.png" alt="" /> </li>
                 <li> <img src="slide2.png" alt="" /> </li>
                 <li> <img src="slide3.png" alt="" /> </li>
             </ul>
         </figure>
     </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the below slider with no javascript and jquery libraries. I hope this will be helpful for you.

```css
html, body { background: #333 url("https://codepen.io/images/classy_fabric.png"); }

.slides {
    padding: 0;
    width: 609px;
    height: 420px;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
}

.slides * {
    user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
}

.slides input { display: none; }

.slide-container { display: block; }

.slide {
    top: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    width: 609px;
    height: 420px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;

    transform: scale(0);

    transition: all .7s ease-in-out;
}

.slide img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.nav label {
    width: 80px;
    height: 100%;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
   opacity: 0;
    z-index: 9;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: opacity .2s;
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 156pt;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 380px;
    font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .3);
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 15px rgb(119, 119, 119);
}

.slide:hover + .nav label { opacity: 0.5; }

.nav label:hover { opacity: 1; }

.nav .next { right: 0; }

input:checked + .slide-container  .slide {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1);
    transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}

input:checked + .slide-container .nav label { display: block; }

.nav-dots {
 width: 100%;
 bottom: 9px;
 height: 11px;
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
 text-align: center;
}

.nav-dots .nav-dot {
 top: -5px;
 width: 11px;
 height: 11px;
 margin: 0 4px;
 position: relative;
 border-radius: 100%;
 display: inline-block;
 background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}

.nav-dots .nav-dot:hover {
 cursor: pointer;
 background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

input#img-1:checked ~ .nav-dots label#img-dot-1,
input#img-2:checked ~ .nav-dots label#img-dot-2,
input#img-3:checked ~ .nav-dots label#img-dot-3,
input#img-4:checked ~ .nav-dots label#img-dot-4,
input#img-5:checked ~ .nav-dots label#img-dot-5,
input#img-6:checked ~ .nav-dots label#img-dot-6 {
 background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}
```

```html
<ul class="slides">
    <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-1" checked />
    <li class="slide-container">
  <div class="slide">
   <img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8072/8346734966_f9cd7d0941_z.jpg" />
        </div>
  <div class="nav">
   <label for="img-6" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
   <label for="img-2" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
  </div>
    </li>

    <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-2" />
    <li class="slide-container">
        <div class="slide">
          <img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8504/8365873811_d32571df3d_z.jpg" />
        </div>
  <div class="nav">
   <label for="img-1" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
   <label for="img-3" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
  </div>
    </li>

    <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-3" />
    <li class="slide-container">
        <div class="slide">
          <img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8068/8250438572_d1a5917072_z.jpg" />
        </div>
  <div class="nav">
   <label for="img-2" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
   <label for="img-4" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
  </div>
    </li>

    <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-4" />
    <li class="slide-container">
        <div class="slide">
          <img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8061/8237246833_54d8fa37f0_z.jpg" />
        </div>
  <div class="nav">
   <label for="img-3" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
   <label for="img-5" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
  </div>
    </li>

    <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-5" />
    <li class="slide-container">
        <div class="slide">
          <img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8055/8098750623_66292a35c0_z.jpg" />
        </div>
  <div class="nav">
   <label for="img-4" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
   <label for="img-6" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
  </div>
    </li>

    <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-6" />
    <li class="slide-container">
        <div class="slide">
          <img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8195/8098750703_797e102da2_z.jpg" />
        </div>
  <div class="nav">
   <label for="img-5" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
   <label for="img-1" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
  </div>
    </li>

    <li class="nav-dots">
      <label for="img-1" class="nav-dot" id="img-dot-1"></label>
      <label for="img-2" class="nav-dot" id="img-dot-2"></label>
      <label for="img-3" class="nav-dot" id="img-dot-3"></label>
      <label for="img-4" class="nav-dot" id="img-dot-4"></label>
      <label for="img-5" class="nav-dot" id="img-dot-5"></label>
      <label for="img-6" class="nav-dot" id="img-dot-6"></label>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
    $('ol li').bind('click', function(){
        
        var index = $(this).index() + 1;
        
        $(".active").fadeOut(300);
        
        $("#slide_" + index).fadeIn(300);        
        $(".slide").removeClass("active");
        $("#slide_" + index).addClass("active");
    });
```

```html
<div class="banner-container revolution">
                <div class="banner" id="slider">
                <figure>
                    <ul >
                        <li> <img id="slide_1" src="slide1.png" alt="" />
                        </li>
                        <li> <img id="slide_2" src="slide2.png" alt="" />
                        </li>
                        <li> <img id="slide_3" src="slide3.png" alt="" />
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                  </figure>
                </div>
            </div>
             <ol>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
    </ol>
```

```js
    $('ol li').bind('click', function(){
        
        var index = $(this).index() + 1;
        
        $(".active").fadeOut(300);
        
        $("#slide_" + index).fadeIn(300);        
        $(".slide").removeClass("active");
        $("#slide_" + index).addClass("active");
    });
```

```html
 <div class="banner-container revolution">
                <div class="banner" id="slider">
                <figure>
                    <ul >
                        <li> <img id="slide_1" src="slide1.png" alt="" />
                        </li>
                        <li> <img id="slide_2" src="slide2.png" alt="" />
                        </li>
                        <li> <img id="slide_3" src="slide3.png" alt="" />
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                  </figure>
                </div>
            </div>
             <ol>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
    </ol>
```

Comment: Would you add more explanation?